# CSS background position relative to cursor

Tags: javascript, css, background, position

I'm wondering how to do an effect like this:
http://www.gazprom.com/

(please note, the moving blue background, in top blue menu), and its relativity to cursor position)

Is there any script that follows cursor and changes background position style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect can be achieved using small piece of JavaScript:

### JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (window.event) { // IE fix
        event = window.event;
    }

    // Grab the mouse's X-position.
    var mousex = event.clientX;
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    header.style.backgroundPosition = mousex/3 + 'px 0';
}, false);
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/anDFd/300/)

### How it works :

1. It binds a function on the `mousemove` event on `document`.
2. It grabs the current mouse position using `event.clientX`.
3. It changes the background-position of element `#header` with 1/3rd of the speed (`mousex/3`). [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373831/how-to-move-background-according-to-cursor-hover)